# Linux permissions in dual-booting scenario

Tags: windows-7, linux, multi-boot, arch-linux

This may sound like an odd request, but I'm currently dual-booting Arch with Win7, and I'm using Variety on Arch to switch wallpapers.

The problem is that the wallpapers are on the Win7 partition, and Variety refuses to switch wallpapers unless i manually set the path to the wallpaper folder everytime. And then it only switches once and it stops.

Is there some way to get around this without having to copy my wallpaper folder to the Linux partition ?

Comment: How did you determine that it's a permissions problem?

Comment: Because everytime i try to mount that partition it asks for my password. However, it is just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far my guess is that the password requirement when mounting is a red herring.

The real problem is that you have to manually mount the partition at all. And you do this after Variety has started. So it starts, looks for wallpapers, decides that they're gone, and resets the path.

You need to have the partition mounted on boot, which is done through **fstab** – the `/etc/fstab` file needs to list the partition.

If using GNOME, you can configure this through **`gnome-disks`**, under its "Change Mount Settings" option. Otherwise add the entry manually – it should look roughly like this:

```
/dev/disk/by-label/raindows /win ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000
```

Here "/win" would be the path on which to mount the disk.

(The full format is described in `man fstab`; the by-label and by-uuid paths somewhere in Archwiki.)

Comment: After many failed attempts with gn ome-disks, i finally got it to work with this line in fstab: `/dev/sdb3                       /home/Media     ntfs-3g         rw,user,exec,auto,uid=1000      0 0`

Comment: Writing directly to the file was strangely easier than `gnome-disks`. I don't know if all those extra options are necessary, but I'll just leave them there for now. Thanks a million !